# The expression must be a modifiable l-value

Tags: c++, lvalue

I've been writing a simple data base in C++ using my basic object programming skills and I've come across a problem that I don't know how to get through. In one on my methods I'm trying to check correct forma of an input provided by a user. In order to achive that I need to know how long is the input string. Unfortunately an error pops out that the expression has to me modifiable l-value. I've searched for the answer, but I didn't really understand the solutions. Could you please, in layman terms, explain to me what did I do wrong?
Thank you!

The structure of the class I'm working with:

```
class Item
{
  public:
  void checkPNA()
  {
    if ((pna.length() = !6)||(pna[2]=!"-"))
    {
        cout<<endl<< "Niepoprawny format kody pocztowego! Poprawny format: \"00-000\". Spróbuj ponownie: ";
    }
  }
  string nazwisko, imie, ulica, pna, miasto, attrib;
  int id, len;
};
```

Comment: Please provide full error message that you get and [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Simple syntax errors, it's `!=` not `= !` or `=!`, and it's `'-'` not `"-"` for a character.

```
if ((pna.length() = !6)||(pna[2]=!"-"))
```

should be

```
if ((pna.length() != 6) || (pna[2] != '-'))
```

You also don't need all those brackets

```
if (pna.length() != 6 || pna[2] != '-')
```

is easier to read in my opinion.

Comment: THANK you, I can't believe I did not see that myself

Comment: Too many brackets, not enough spaces stopped you seeing, possibly.